# org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm new to Hibernate.

- Automatically created hibernate.cfg.xml (Netbeans wizard)
- Automatically created HibernateUtil.java
- Automatically created POJO class with annotations

Trying to get object from database but getting error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:297)
```

getting an object:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
CallInfo ci = (CallInfo) session.get(CallInfo.class, ucid);
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sochi_feedback</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that calls the get() method??

Comment: @ShashankKadne `CallInfo ci = (CallInfo) session.get(CallInfo.class, ucid);`

Comment: Add "Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();" just before this line and at the end of your operations call "tx.commit();"

Comment: :I ll add it as an answer then...

Comment: why eclipse hibernate tool doesn't automatically generate this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add

`Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();` //This statement will initiate the transaction

just before your `CallInfo ci = (CallInfo) session.get(CallInfo.class, ucid);`

and at the end of your transaction commit the changes by calling..

```
tx.commit();
```

Comment: why eclipse hibernate tool doesn't automatically generate this?

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to use `openSession()` instead of `getCurrentSession()`. Then transactions can be used only when required for updating queries.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
CallInfo ci = (CallInfo) session.get(CallInfo.class, ucid);
```

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly this, i.e. that sessions obtained via getCurrentSession requires a transaction even for get-operations, whereas this does not apply when using openSession. Why is that? (I had thought that the session-objects are identical?)

Comment: I had the same issue. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Even after `beginTransaction()` and and `commit()` if you still get the

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: setDefaultReadOnly is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
```

go to  "Start"  and search for services and restart the database service

Answer (score 0):

Before you actually start the transaction you need to start the session by calling `session.beginTransaction()`, right after you create sessionFactory.