# Hibernate 5 Transaction not started by Spring 4

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, spring-4, hibernate-5.x

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example), I was trying to manage Hibernate 5 transactions with Spring 4. It seems that the transaction has not been started when session.get() method is reached. How does Spring knows when to start and end a transaction? Shouldn't the @Transactional annotation do precisely this?

**Entity**

```
package coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities.Project;
import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities.User;

@Entity
@Table( name = "users" )
public class Cbtion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne
    private User creator;

    private Date creationDate;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }
    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
    public User getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }
    public void setCreator(User creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }
    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
package coproject.cpweb.utils.db.daos;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities.User;

@Service
public class CbtionDAO {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void saveUser(User user) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user_indb = session.get(User.class,user.getId());
        if(user_indb == null) {
            session.save(user);
        }
        else {
            user = user_indb;
        }
    }

    public User getUser(Integer id) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User user = session.get(User.class,id);
        return user;
    }

}
```

**Service**

```
package coproject.cpweb.utils.db.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import coproject.cpweb.utils.DbServicesIf;
import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.daos.CbtionDAO;
import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities.User;

@Service
public class DbServicesImp implements DbServicesIf{

    @Autowired
    private CbtionDAO cbtionDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        cbtionDAO.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public User getUser(Integer id) {
        return cbtionDAO.getUser(id);
    }
}
```

**context beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd" >

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="coproject.cpweb.utils.db.daos" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="coproject.cpweb.utils.db.services" />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
       <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
       <property name="username" value="jaof" />
       <property name="password" value="iris" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Main**

```
package coproject.cploc;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.entities.User;
import coproject.cpweb.utils.db.services.DbServicesImp;

public class FillRandomDb {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

    // TEST String[] bean_names = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();

       DbServicesImp dbServices = (DbServicesImp) context.getBean("dbServicesImp");

       User user = new User();
       user.setUsername("johndoe");
       user.setFirstname("John");
       user.setLastname("Doe");

       dbServices.saveUser(user);

       User user_ret = dbServices.getUser(user.getId());

       System.out.println(user_ret.getFirstname());

}

}
```

**Stack**

```
nov 29, 2015 1:45:37 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@506e6d5e: startup date [Sun Nov 29 13:45:37 CE
T 2015]; root of context hierarchy
nov 29, 2015 1:45:37 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
nov 29, 2015 1:45:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
nov 29, 2015 1:45:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.2.Final}
nov 29, 2015 1:45:38 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
nov 29, 2015 1:45:38 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
nov 29, 2015 1:45:38 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
nov 29, 2015 1:45:39 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
nov 29, 2015 1:45:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
nov 29, 2015 1:45:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
nov 29, 2015 1:45:46 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@5e1d03d7] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionMana
ger
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: get is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:33
4)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.get(Unknown Source)
    at coproject.cpweb.utils.db.daos.CbtionDAO.saveUser(CbtionDAO.java:19)
    at coproject.cpweb.utils.db.services.DbServicesImp.saveUser(DbServicesImp.java:20)
    at coproject.cpweb.utils.db.services.DbServicesImp$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cd649fcb.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281
)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at coproject.cpweb.utils.db.services.DbServicesImp$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75288f15.saveUser(<generated>)
    at coproject.cploc.FillRandomDb.main(FillRandomDb.java:24)
```

Comment: you try it : http://www.journaldev.com/2900/solved-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-get-is-not-valid-without-active-transaction

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717906/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-get-is-not-valid-without-active-transaction

Comment: thanks for the links. They explain how to start the transaction manually. Is there a way for Spring to automatically start the transaction? I purposely dont want to do it manually with `session.beginTransaction()` within the DAO

Comment: you add @transactional on the method and on the class. the spring will take of it.

Comment: @Transactional is already annotated in the methods of `DbServicesImp`. Adding the anoation to the class itself did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line in your file **context beans.xml**:

```
  <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
```

With this line:

```
 <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop >
```

And for annotation support, in your spring config bean, add this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="proxy" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: thanks, changing only the `current_session_context_class` parameter was enough. Its a bit frustrating... how did you know?... there was no mention at all to it in the error trace...

Comment: In fact, on my side it also helps to just remove the parameter hibernate.current_session_context_class - I don't think that the changed parameter name current_session_context_class has any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

DAO class should be annotated as @Repository.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but addind the @Repository annotation to CbtionDAO class did not solve the problem. Same exception.

Comment: this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788158/spring-jdbc-transaction-manager